# Powershell replace regex between two tags

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a block of arbitrary text enclosed by specific tags, I would like to replace the whole chunk with something else (in the example, "BANANA")

`$newvar = $oldvar -replace "<!-- URL -->(*.)<!-- END -->","BANANA"`

Is there a mode in PS regex to not require escaping and can the syntax then be as simple as this to achieve the replacement?

**UPDATE:** I understand now that it should be `.*`, not `*.`, but still no dice. The match covers multiple lines, if that adds complexity to the regex or requires other options.

Comment: are you sure it is `(*.)` and not `(.*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you have the `.*` in reverse (`*.`). Apart from that, try:

```
$newvar = $oldvar -creplace '(?s)<!-- URL -->.*?<!-- END -->', 'BANANA'
```

- In response to your comments, I have made the `.*?` lazy so it will not "overmatch" (for details on lazy vs. greedy, see the reference section)
- Also in reference to your comments, the `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the `.*?` to match across multiple lines.

**Reference**

[The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)

Comment: Thanks. `-replace "<!-- URL -->","BANANA"`, with `replace` or `creplace` both replace the initial tag, so at least I know now that nothing needs escaping there. However, it is unable to match the whole inner contents. I should add that the contents span multiple lines, perhaps that is it. `(.*)` does not seem to be working...

Comment: That did it, merci beaucoup! (giving you the trophy in T minus 3 minutes ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Okay, I'm counting down with you, but also trying to hold my breath at the same time. :)

Comment: oops, hope you're still alive! My mental timer is also buggy :P